# How to move files to files with same name, but different extension

Tags: bash, command-line, move

I have a folder A with many small files.
In the parent folder there are many folders with other files in them.
now in folder A there are files that have the same name as in the other folders, but they additionaly have .xmp at the end.

Thats the structure now:

- ~/A/foo.xmp
- ~/A/bar.xmp
- ~/folder1/foo
- ~/folder2/bar

and that is how I want it to be:

- ~/folder1/foo
- ~/folder1/foo.xmp
- ~/folder2/bar
- ~/folder2/bar.xmp

How do I find the coresponding file to foo.xmp (the coresponding file is: foo) in the parent directory and move my file there?

How do I put this in a loop so it goes through all files in my current directory?

Comment: Bash is very trendy at this time of the year. A shame that google and `man` aren't...

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in folder*/
do
    for f in "$dir"*
    do
        base=${f#$dir}
        [ -f "A/$base.xmp" ] && mv "A/$base.xmp" "$dir"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done:

```
#Assuming there are N folders folder1,folder2...folderN
for folder in folder* 
do
cd $folder
for file in *
do
#if file with .xmp extension exists in ~/A folder
[[ -f $file ]] && [[ -f ~/A/$file.xmp ]] && mv ~/A/$file.xmp .
done
cd ..
done
```